# I am trying to build a query and not sure where the problem is?

Tags: sql

I have written the below SQL query to join four tables and do the calculations based on criteria but throws an error. Will appreciate for any help. Thanks

Not sure where I am doing wrong or whether my logic is not right?

```
SELECT C.cust_name,
       R.Reg_name,
       sum(CASE WHEN P.Class = 'R' THEN T.Amount*.1 WHEN P.Class = 'P' THEN T.Amount*.2 ELSE T.Amount*.1 END) AS Calc_Amount
FROM Customers C,
     Regions R,
     transactions T,
     customer_class P
WHERE C.reg_id = R.reg_id, C.cust_id = T.cust_id, C.cust_id = P.cust_id
  AND P.class_id, P.class IN (SELECT max(class_id), class
                              FROM customer_class
                              GROUP BY cust_id)
  AND T.Time, T.Amount IN (SELECT max(time),
                                   Amount
                            FROM transactions
                            GROUP BY cust_id)
GROUP BY C.cust_name
ORDER BY C.cust_name
```

SQL command not properly ended

Comment: Please learn to use modern JOIN syntax. Apart from that the issue seems to be that your WHERE conditions are comma separated, they should be separated by AND or OR. You also have a half strange condition, `AND P.class_id` that seems to miss the second part

Comment: @JoakimDanielson - the part with `P.class_id, P.class` looks like it should be `...(P.class_id, P.class) IN (SELECT max(class_id), class...`. Ditto and likewise `T.Time, T.Amount` should be in parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

You can't combine multiple conditions with an `,` in the  WHERE clause. You probably want an and there:

```
WHERE C.reg_id = R.reg_id
  AND C.cust_id = T.cust_id
  AND C.cust_id = P.cust_id
```

But I strongly recommend to switch to an explicit `JOIN` in the FROM clause:

```
FROM Customers C 
  JOIN Regions R ON C.reg_id = R.reg_id
  JOIN transactions T ON C.cust_id = T.cust_id
  JOIN customer_class P ON C.cust_id = P.cust_id
```

Additionally, when you want to use multiple columns with an IN operator, you need to enclose the columns on the left hand side with parentheses, e.g. `(P.class_id, P.class)` instead of `P.class_id, P.class`.

You also need to include all columns that are not used in an aggregation in the `group by` clause.

So the complete query should look something like:

```sql
SELECT C.cust_name,
       R.Reg_name,
       sum(CASE WHEN P.Class = 'R' THEN T.Amount*.1 WHEN P.Class = 'P' THEN T.Amount*.2 ELSE T.Amount*.1 END) AS Calc_Amount
FROM Customers C 
  JOIN Regions R ON C.reg_id = R.reg_id
  JOIN transactions T ON C.cust_id = T.cust_id
  JOIN customer_class P ON C.cust_id = P.cust_id
WHERE (P.class_id, P.class) IN (SELECT max(class_id), class
                                FROM customer_class
                                GROUP BY cust_id)
  AND (T.Time, T.Amount) IN (SELECT max(time), Amount
                             FROM transactions
                             GROUP BY cust_id)
GROUP BY C.cust_name, R.Reg_name
ORDER BY C.cust_name
```

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I am now getting "not a GROUP BY expression" error.

Comment: You need to include `R.Reg_name` in the group by

Comment: I added GROUP BY (C.cust_name, R.reg_name); at the end but getting same error. Any idea?

Comment: @UttamDas: don't put the columns between parentheses

Comment: I'm just wondering whether the problem is in the GROUP BY clause within WHERE statement?

Comment: it's not "within" the WERE clause. It's **after** the where clause

Comment: CLASS_ID CUST_ID  TIME                 CLASS
1                   1            20/03/2018                 R
2                   1            03/04/2018                 R
3                   1            05/04/2018           P
4                   2            01/04/2018           P
5                   2            04/04/2018                 P
6                   3            01/04/2018                 R - I would like to achieve max(class_id) (latest time?) by cust_id but also need to take amount column - which is in my sub query.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend proper `join` syntax *and* using window functions.  I think you want something like this:

```
SELECT C.cust_name, 
       sum(CASE WHEN P.Class = 'R' THEN T.Amount*.1 WHEN P.Class = 'P' THEN T.Amount*.2 ELSE T.Amount*.1 END) AS Calc_Amount
FROM Customers C JOIN
     Regions R
     C.reg_id = R.reg_id JOIN
     (SELECT T.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T.cust_id ORDER BY T.Time DESC) as seqnum
      FROM transactions T
     ) T
     ON C.cust_id = T.cust_id AND seqnum = 1 JOIN
     (SELECT P.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY P.cust_id ORDER BY P.class_id DESC) as seqnum
      FROM customer_class P
     ) P
     ON C.cust_id = P.cust_id
GROUP BY C.cust_name
ORDER BY C.cust_name;
```

However, I'm not sure that this logic does anything useful.  You should probably ask a *new* question with sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Building on @a_horse_with_no_name's answer - the problem is with the `GROUP BY` expressions in the subqueries in the WHERE clause. It looks like you should be using

```
SELECT C.cust_name,
       R.Reg_name,
       sum(CASE WHEN P.Class = 'R' THEN T.Amount*.1 WHEN P.Class = 'P' THEN T.Amount*.2 ELSE T.Amount*.1 END) AS Calc_Amount
FROM Customers C 
  JOIN Regions R ON C.reg_id = R.reg_id
  JOIN transactions T ON C.cust_id = T.cust_id
  JOIN customer_class P ON C.cust_id = P.cust_id
WHERE (P.class_id, P.class) IN (SELECT max(class_id), class
                                FROM customer_class
                                GROUP BY class)
  AND (T.Time, T.Amount) IN (SELECT max(time), Amount
                             FROM transactions
                             GROUP BY amount)
GROUP BY C.cust_name, R.Reg_name
ORDER BY C.cust_name
```

That will probably execute, but I'm not sure it'll give you the results you wanted. Another possibility is

```
SELECT C.cust_name,
       R.Reg_name,
       sum(CASE WHEN P.Class = 'R' THEN T.Amount*.1 WHEN P.Class = 'P' THEN T.Amount*.2 ELSE T.Amount*.1 END) AS Calc_Amount
FROM Customers C 
  JOIN Regions R ON C.reg_id = R.reg_id
  JOIN transactions T ON C.cust_id = T.cust_id
  JOIN customer_class P ON C.cust_id = P.cust_id
WHERE (P.class_id, P.class) IN (SELECT max(class_id), class
                                FROM customer_class
                                GROUP BY class)
  AND (T.cust_id, T.Time, T.Amount) IN (SELECT cust_id, max(time), max(Amount)
                                          FROM transactions
                                          GROUP BY cust_id)
GROUP BY C.cust_name, R.Reg_name
ORDER BY C.cust_name
```

but I doubt the second sub-select does what you had in mind. But without test data and expected results it's impossible to understand what you're trying to do. You might consider editing the question and adding test data and expected results **as text, not as an image** so people can test their queries against the expected results.